# Access Spinner in Activity without define in Layout

Tags: android

```
Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this);
String option[]={"By Date","By Transaction ID","By Customer Phone"};
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,option);
spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
spinner.performClick();
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentview, View v,int position, long id)
    {
        Log.d("in select","yes");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this,"no",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("In No select","No");
    }
});
```

This all are done very fine, a new pop up display of Spinner view is generate on the previous view and previous view still display but dim, all focus on this current Spinner

But the problem is when I select any item in this spinner then onItemSelected() should be called but it is not called.

but if I write

`setContentView(spinner);`

then onItemSelected() is called, but then previous view is not displayed now.

so how can i access spinner without this line `setContentView(spinner);`

I want to get the position of the selected Item in Spinner

Please provide me code or example

i am waiting for your kind reply

Comment: hey is there any one to help me

Comment: int pos = 0;object t=m_adapterForSpinner.getitem(pos);//whr m_arrayadapter is array adapter using for filling spinner

Comment: you need to be a little more patient. You cannot place a question and demand to be answered immediately.

Comment: i want to get position in onItemSelected() method, but it is not called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must bind your spinner to your Layout, if you don't wont to use `setContentView(spinner);`. Use something like this at the end of your code

```
LinearLayout line = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.line);
line.addView(spinner);
```

and your Layout is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/line">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i dont want to add Spinner in layout